# Asterisk cannot run agi script with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, asterisk

I created python script to run some task.
When I excute this script by python compile, it work like a charm.

```
python test.py
```

But when I call test.py from Asterisk agi, I cannot get timestamp.

```
exten => 201,n,agi(test.py,"おはようございます")
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
#from asterisk.agi import *

#agi = AGI()
#agi.verbose("python agi started")
#agi.verbose("params : " +agi.env['agi_arg_1'])

open_jtalk = ['open_jtalk']
mech = ['-x', '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/open-jtalk/1.10_1/dic']
htsvoice = ['-m', '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/open-jtalk/1.10_1/voice/mei/mei_normal.htsvoice']
speed = ['-r', '1.0']

print "nothing to lose"
timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print "time : " + timestamp
file_name = 'tts_output' + str(timestamp) + '.wav'
file_name_output = 'tts_output' + str(timestamp) + '_8000.wav'
outwav = ['-ow', '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/' + file_name]
cmd = open_jtalk + mech + htsvoice + speed + outwav
print "cmd : "
c = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
c.stdin.write("おはようございます")
c.stdin.close()
c.wait()

print "AAAAAAA"
#agi.verbose("command line is completed")

sox = ['sox']
samplerate = ['-r', '8000']
file_input = [file_name]
file_output = [file_name_output]
sox_command = sox  + file_input + samplerate + file_output
ds = subprocess.Popen(sox_command)
ds.wait()
```

when run test.py, console is printed "nothing to lose", but next command cannot excute.

```
timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

Can someone help me? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the file executable? You should be able to run it just as `test.py`.

Comment: Finally I can excuted my script. My problem is running test.py as root(because asterisk running as root). I try to running asterisk as another user and my script work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import time
>>> timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
>>> print "time : " + timestamp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Try `print "time : {}".format(timestamp)`